# regular expressions, text wrangler, inserting line breaks in certain places

Tags: regex, textwrangler

I have a large file. Most lines are like this 
(record number dot space last name, first name)

```
1. Moore, Roger
2. Connery, Sean
3. ....
100. Dalton, Timothy
```

..
Occasionally some  unpleasant lines are like this

```
110. Bronson, Pierce  111. Gomez, Selena 112. Portman, Nathalie
```

I need a regular expression to break those unpleasent lines to like this

```
110. Bronson, Pierce  
111. Gomez, Selena 
112. Portman, Nathalie
```

Some lines may have two records, but some may have five or more records like that.
How did I get them, when I copy/paste pdf document into Textwrangler some lines come up like that.
I use text wrangler.

Comment: you could insert a newline in front of every `\d+` that is not anchored by a `^`.

Comment: I am really a novice, could you please type up your reply as a command that I could enter in search replace box text wrangler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used *Text Wrangler* in years, but it has regex capabilities. You need to **Find and Replace** with a regex.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/FlgUYl/1) is a working regex that shows the identification of all the lines with extra numbered entries.

You want to replace what it matches with something like

```
\n$1
```

where the `\n` is a newline character and the `$1` is the text captured in the match, so it should result in

> 110. Bronson, Pierce  111. Gomez, Selena 112. Portman, Nathalie

going to

> 110. Bronson, Pierce
> 111. Gomez, Selena
> 112. Portman, Nathalie

Comment: Thanks lot; it worked; I typed  ( )(\d+)  in the search box and typed  \n\2  in the replace box.

Comment: good. you should close this question out by checking the green tick on this answer. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: [`+(?=\d+\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/M0F3cK/2) or `\s+(?=\d+\.)` **Substitution**: `\n`

Details:

- `\s` Matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `(?=)` Positive Lookahead
- `\d` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)